# How can i prevent User from directly accessing the HTML page

Tags: rest

I have got a set 3 HTML Pages

I am using Apache Tomcat 7 server . I have got the following HTML pages (All are HTML pages only)

```
login.html 
sales.html
index.html
```

The code for the login.html is when clicked on submit is

```
<input type="email" name="email"  id="email"  >
<input type="pin" name="email"  id="pin"  >
 <button class="primary login-btn">Submit</button>
```

Once clicked on Submit button , i am calling a Jersey REST Webservce this way and will response either true OR false based on the values present in our Database

```
function submitLoginForm() {
  var email_input = $.trim($("#email").val());
  var pin_input = $.trim($("#pin").val());
  var logininfo = {
    'email': email_input,
    'pin': pin_input
  };
  var login_information = JSON.stringify(logininfo);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: login_information,
    url: url + '/HEGS/orn/webchecklogin',
    success: function(response) {
    // if true , redirect to sales.html page 
    window.location = "index.html"

    },
  });
}
```

All this is working fine , my issue  is , how can i stop the prevent the user from accessing the page directly

For example if he types the follwing URL

http:localhost:8080/HEGS/dealer/sales.html

Answer (score 0):

You would want to redirect the url to one file, which would then load the correct file based on the criteria you set. I don't know much about Tomcat, but [this article](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/printer/proxy.html) seems to explain it well under the "URL Rewriting" section.